# PHP Fetches two rows but uploads file from last row only

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im trying to fetch records from database, then i have to upload a image which should be stored in folder and also link to be updated in table.. Everything working fine only with last row.. For first row its not updating.. Please help me where im goin on.. Below is my code

> [image]

```
<?php
$email1 = $_SESSION['email'];
$Vendor_id = "SELECT Vendor_id FROM vendors where email = '$email1' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $Vendor_id);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$sql = "select Vendor_wallet_id, total_amount, request, amount, status, amt_pdflink from vendor_wallet";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Transfer ID</th>
                <th>Request</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Upload</th>
                <th>Submit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            {
                $cpid = $row['Vendor_wallet_id'];
                $tid = $row['request'];
                $type = $row['amount'];
                $pays = $row['status'];
                $amt = $row['amt_pdflink'];
                ?>
                <tr>    
                    <td value="<?php echo $cpid; ?>" name="cpid"><?php echo $cpid; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tid; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $type; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pays; ?></td>   
                    <td><input type="file" value="<?php echo $amt; ?>" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" ></td> 
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" >
                        </button>
                    </td>  </tr>
            <?php } ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

upload.php is taken from https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: It's difficult to assess the problem when you have not shown the complete code you are using. Linking to w3schools.com does not count as showing your code.

Comment: thank u so much urfusion.. ur suggestion helped me out...

Comment: Actually a `Form` can not be child of `table` so either change your html structure or use divs to create table.

Comment: I think the problem is with input fields naming. You are using the same names for all rows. The id's also no proper because the case is the same. You should not use same ids and names for file input. Make them as array or use rows id to make the field name/id.

Comment: You cannot have duplicated IDs in your HTML

Comment: If file cannot be child of table,, then how should i submit the button.. Is there any way to submit button without form

Comment: a form can be a child of a table cell or you can have a single form and use javascript to submit the form with the appropriate values ~ or remove the form altogether and use only javascript

Comment: are you trying to upload multiple files into single or selecting from all the rows and hiting submit of single row?

Comment: no,, uploading single file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your form

```
<?php
$email1 = $_SESSION['email'];
$Vendor_id = "SELECT Vendor_id FROM vendors where email = '$email1' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $Vendor_id);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$sql = "select Vendor_wallet_id, total_amount, request, amount, status, amt_pdflink from vendor_wallet";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Transfer ID</th>
                <th>Request</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Upload</th>
                <th>Submit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            {
                $cpid = $row['Vendor_wallet_id'];
                $tid = $row['request'];
                $type = $row['amount'];
                $pays = $row['status'];
                $amt = $row['amt_pdflink'];
                ?>
                <tr>    
                    <td value="<?php echo $cpid; ?>" name="cpid"><?php echo $cpid; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tid; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $type; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pays; ?></td>   
                    <td><input type="file" name="fileToUpload []" class="fileToUpload" ></td> 
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $amt; ?>" name="fileToUploadLink []" class="fileToUploadLink" >
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" >
                        </button>
                    </td>  </tr>
            <?php } ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

on upload.php

```
<?php
 if(isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])&&isset($_POST['fileToUploadLink'])){
  for($i=0;$i<=(count($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])-1);$i++){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$i],$_POST['fileToUploadLink'][$i]);
  }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways in which you could do the file upload, one of which would be to make the form a child of a single table cell and have the file field as a direct child of that form. The `submit` button, to keep the layout, would not be a child of the form and would need to be changed to a simple `button` input type then use javascript to submit the form

```
<?php
    $email1 = $_SESSION['email'];
    $Vendor_id = "SELECT Vendor_id FROM vendors where email = '$email1' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $Vendor_id);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $sql = "select Vendor_wallet_id, total_amount, request, amount, status, amt_pdflink from vendor_wallet";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>

    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Transfer ID</th>
                <th>Request</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Upload</th>
                <th>Submit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

<?php

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $query ) ) {
        $cpid = $row['Vendor_wallet_id'];
        $tid = $row['request'];
        $type = $row['amount'];
        $pays = $row['status'];
        $amt = $row['amt_pdflink'];
?>
    <tr>    
        <td value="<?php echo $cpid; ?>" name="cpid"><?php echo $cpid; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tid; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $type; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pays; ?></td>   
        <td>
            <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" value="<?php echo $amt; ?>" name="fileToUpload" />
            </form>
        </td>   
        <td><input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" /></td> 
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>

        </tbody>
    </table>



<script>
    var bttns=Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"][name="submit"]'));
        bttns.forEach(function(bttn){
            bttn.addEventListener('click',function(evt){
                this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('form').submit();
            }.bind(bttn),false );
        });
</script>
```

Comment: @urfusion and the link is for?

Comment: I suggest you look carefully at Quentin's answer - it cannot be a child of a table, tbody or tr but it is valid within a table cell

Comment: Ahh, My bad. Sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions:

1. In your "php.ini" file, search for the file_uploads directive, and set it to On: file_uploads = On
2. ...`</button><!-- <<-- How are you using this? -->`
3. Could try to echo $amt; at the bottom of the loop to see if the path is correct.
4. May want to check if the $amt with IF Empty condition/statement and maybe check the condition of your other variables.

   ```
               $email1 = $_SESSION['email'];
               $Vendor_id="SELECT Vendor_id FROM vendors where email = '$email1' ";
               $result=mysqli_query($conn,$Vendor_id);
               $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
               $sql = "select Vendor_wallet_id, total_amount, request, amount, status, amt_pdflink from vendor_wallet";
               $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
           ?>

                <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

             <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">

               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>Transfer ID</th>
                       <th>Request</th>
                       <th>Amount</th>
                       <th>Status</th>
                       <th>Upload</th>
                       <th>Submit</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>

               <?php

               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
               {                                                       
                       $cpid=$row['Vendor_wallet_id'];
                       $tid=$row['request'];
                       $type=$row['amount'];
                       $pays=$row['status'];
                       $amt=$row['amt_pdflink'];
               ?>

                       <tr>    
                       <td value="<?php echo $cpid; ?>" name="cpid"><?php echo $cpid;?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $tid;?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $type;?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $pays;?></td>    
                       <td><input type="file" value="<?php echo $amt;?>" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" ></td>  
                       <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" >
                       </button> <!-- WHY IS THIS HERE? -->
                       </td></tr>

           <?php 

               echo $amt; //See if it is correct path

           }//END WHILE ?>

         </tbody>
        </table>
     </form>
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like You want to make a form per row.

```
<tr>    
    <td value="<?php echo $cpid; ?>" name="cpid"><?php echo $cpid; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tid; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $type; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $pays; ?></td>   
    <td colspan="2">
       <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="hidden" name="Vendor_wallet_id" value="<?php echo $cpid;?>" />
         <input type="file" value="<?php echo $amt; ?>" name="fileToUpload" />
         <button>Submit</button>
       </form>
    </td>
</tr>
</form>
```

and remove `<form>` tag that wraps table

Comment: To do this would be incorrect - a form cannot be a child of a table unless it is wholly within a table cell `td` - it cannot span a table row like this

Comment: @RamRaider I know I'm wrong. But I don't care about how correct to wrap a row with form. Question owner wants to upload per file per wallet. And there are 2 ways: 1. To make input field name to represent array `fileToUpload[<?=$cpid?>]` 2. is wrap each row with form cuz submit button is in another column. I know You may tell to us js and handle event listener and emit submit in sibling TD>FORM. But my answer is to minimize using of js. In fact browser handles my example well.

Comment: " I love to know I'm wrong to learn from mistakes" - seems not

Comment: @RamRaider This citation does not have relation to my response. I never do such UI which has mix of PHP and HTML. I answered nooby way to nooby question.